# How many channels does the VOR have?

Tags: navigation, vor

VORs are assigned radio channels between 108.0 MHz and 117.95 MHz. **How many channels are in-between? I guess that each decimal value represents 1 channel?** for instance (108.1)(108.2)(108.3)(108.4)......(117.94)(117.95).

Sorry If my question looks dumb, I'm not professional but student.

Answer (score 15):

As shown by this [Source](https://mediawiki.ivao.aero/index.php?title=VHF_Omnidirectional_Range_-_VOR_(Instrument)):

> VOR are exploited over the Very High Frequency (VHF) band from 108 to 117.95 MHz with channels spaced of 50 or 100 kHz (50 kHz for dense zones, 100 kHz elsewhere). The first 4 MHz is shared with the ILS (Instrument Landing System) band, **the VOR being allocated to 160 of the 200 available channels.** To leave channels for the ILS, in the range 108.0 to 111.95 MHz, the 100 kHz digit is always even. Of these 160 channels, 120 are allocated to VOR stations intended for en route navigation while the other forty are for terminal VOR stations.

(emphasis is mine)

Comment: Is it possible to have more than 200 channels?

Comment: @knowledgeloverx Based on the existing frequency allocation program for VOR stations and Localizer channels in the U.S., I don't think so.

Comment: thank you for responses

Comment: @knowledgeloverx The system as it is today is designed with 160 channels. It would be possible to change the system to a different system that has more channels, but that would probably be extremely difficult in practice.

Comment: The channels are reused when the transmitters are far enough apart to ensure there can be no interference, so 160 usable channels are enough to cover the entire planet.

Comment: @PaulSmith  That's a good point.  In the U.S., as of October of 2021, there were almost **900** VOR/VORTAC/VOR-DME stations of which about **113** had been discontinued (with **193** more scheduled to be discontinued) under the MON (Minimum Operational Network) program.

Comment: @knowledgeloverx it is technically feasible to reduce the channel spacing substantially as the information being broadcast is small and based on a very low modulation frequency. However, aside from a need for aircraft new receivers, this would decrease the margin for error in the equipment and increase problems with interference and background noise. For a decrease below 25kHz spacing there would need to be a reduction in the subcarrier offset which is currently 9.96kHz.

Comment: The transmitted signal is distributed in frequency over a bandwidth that is equal to twice the highest modulation frequency in the signal. The broadcaster determines the bandwidth of the transmitted signal by choosing the high-frequency cutoff of the modulating information. In VOR two signals are modulated at 30hz (Not including morse or voice.) One on the primary frequency, the subcarrier offset 9.96khz, wide enough for voice overlay. One AM the other FM, one fixed one rotating. Which depends on beacon type. Receivers compare the phase offset of the two 30hz sinewaves to determine the radial.

Comment: Reasonable human voice can be had with a 4kHz cutoff, requiring at least 8kHz frequency band, plus the guard band. This is what traditional telephone companies used to get maximum signals per wire with the minimum quality accepted by customers, and is the source of the European 8.333kHz spacing in the aviation voice band. (Which is also 25kHz spacing divided by 3) Assuming sufficient equipment the 25kHz standard can provide almost the complete human voice range including upper harmonics; while adequate 8.33kHz inherently discards significant quality.(lossy compression like jpeg)

Answer (score 8):

VORs are assigned frequencies with 50kHz (or 0.05MHz spacing, if you prefer). Thus, there are 200 possible frequencies.

(In the US, 40 of those frequencies are reserved for ILS, so the total number of available VOR frequencies in the US is 160.)

Answer (score 6):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VHF_omnidirectional_range):

> VORs are assigned radio channels between 108.0 MHz and 117.95 MHz (with 50 kHz spacing);

This means the lowest channel is 108.0MHz, the next one up is 108.05MHz, and so on.

This gives (117.95-108.8)/0.05 + 1 channels, or **200**.